# name for this type of number

Tags: number-theory

Is there a name for this:

for a given number, take the next higher ten's place, ie:

1234 - take 10000

then subtract the first number from that number

10000 - 1234 = 8766

Is there a name for the resulting 8766 and/or its relationship to the 1234?

Comment: "next higher ten´s place" meaning: "the next" power of ten?

Comment: A relationship is given by the formula
$$x\mapsto 10^{\lceil \log_{10} x\rceil} - x$$
Wich is waht you explained in words, turned into mathematical functions. As for the name, see the other answers: 10's complement.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the "ten's complement".  It was once commonly used on mechanical base-10 calculators, but is rarely seen today.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements

If you study basic computer stuff, you will probably see the two's complement, a corresponding construction for base 2.

Comment: awesome, that's the name I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

OEIS has an entry https://oeis.org/A061601 but they don't have a special name as far as I know. If you graph them, you get a sawtooth wave with increasing amplitude with peaks at $8,89,899,8999,\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

The term is a bit ambiguous, but "10's complement" is pretty common.